# api authentcation in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am working on authentication in nodeJs using passport,jwt.I have created api.It works on fine in postman.But I stuck in rendering front end side with error message.My api is:

```
app.post('/api/login',(req, res, next) => {
        if (req.body.name == '' || req.body.password == '') {
            res.json({
                message: 'Please fill all the fields'
            })
            req.flash('errorMsg', 'Please fill all the fields')
        } else if (!regExp.test(req.body.name)) {
            res.json({
                message: 'Only alphabets and numbers are allowed'
            })
        } else if ((req.body.password.length < 4)) {
            res.json({
                message: 'Password must be 4 character length and more'
            })
        }
        else {

            let user = users[_.findIndex(users, {
                name: req.body.name
            })];
            if (user === undefined) {
                res.status(401).json({
                    message: 'User not defined'
                })

            } else {
                if (user.password === req.body.password) {
                    let payload = {
                        id: user.id
                    };
                    let token = jwt.sign(payload, config.jwtSecret);
                    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
                    res.json({
                        message: "ok",
                        token: token
                    });

                } else {
                    res.status(401).json({
                        message: 'Password did not match'
                    })

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

How can i display these errors on front end side.I am using handlebars for as a viewing engine.For example if password didnt match then show password  error message on front end side.I already setup middleware which uses passport jwt strategy.

Comment: You are creating an API. An API is backend only. Someone else must send a request to your API and use the response. If you have other routes that use res.render instead of res.json then you should use javascript's XHR (AJAX) request to get the message you want ( and also submit the form )

Answer (score 0):

> "How can i display these errors on front end side"

You would have to catch/handle the error thrown from the server side on the client side, as noted by itsUndefined you should use an AJAX request and handle errors (identified by the status code) that are sent as a response from the your server side.

You could then show an alert box stating the error that's occurred. Below is an example of what this might look like in the case of utilizing query ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax("www.yourapplication.com/api/login", {
    dataType:"JSON"
    data: { password=password, name='example' }
}).succes(function (result) {
    // redirect to authenticated page
}).error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('Error message');
});
```

Comment: This is a great start to your first answer. However, It'd be great to include a working code sample with this answer so that the answer is of high quality and can be accepted by the OP